# Insert ObjectId into mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, testing, mocking, mongomock

I'm working on a mongo database which, for some reason, has the user id stored as `ObjectId`.

In order to test some functions, I'd like to be able to populate a test database - for example, as follows:

```
import mongomock
from bson import ObjectId

client = mongomock.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/test-database")
database = client.get_default_database()
database.test_collection.insert({'_id': ObjectId('my_user_id'), 'value': 'my_value'})
```

However, running this returns

> InvalidId: 'my_user_id' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte
>   input or a 24-character hex string

How can I correctly insert an ObjectId object into my test database, so I can test querying it using

```
database.test_collection.find_one({'user': ObjectId('my_user_id')})
```

(which works fine when I query the real database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use, as the InvalidId message states, a 12-byte 'binary' input or a 24-character string of hexadecimal characters.

So, if you wan to use something like 'my_user_id' you'll need to use the binary or hex representation, also, is missing two characters to by 12-byte or 24-hex.

For example, if your user id is 'my_user_id00', then you can use any of these:

```py
database.test_collection.find_one({'user': ObjectId(b'my_user_id00')})
```

```py
database.test_collection.find_one({'user': ObjectId('6d795f757365725f69643030')})
```

You can find more info on the [mongoDB API docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html).

Answer (score 0):

By default when inserting documents in the collection, if you don't add a field name with the _id in the field name, then MongoDB will automatically add an Object id field as shown below![enter image description here]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6VDQ.png)

So, when performing insert query use _id as like this...

```
database.test_collection.insert({'_id': 'my_user_id', 'value': 'my_value'})
```

If you want to ensure that MongoDB does not create the _id Field when the collection is created and if you want to specify your own id as the _id of the collection, then you need to explicitly define this while creating the collection..